# How to page brake (DevExpress datagrid grouping Column Header wise) in PrintingSystem using vb.net?

Tags: datagrid, devexpress, grouping

How to page brake (DevExpress datagrid grouping Column Header wise) in PrintingSystem using vb.net?

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a page break before/after printing each group-row using the [GridView.BeforePrintRow](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_BeforePrintRowtopic)/[GridView.AfterPrintRow](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_AfterPrintRowtopic) events.
For example as follows:

```
// C#
void gridView1_BeforePrintRow(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Printing.PrintRowEventArgs e) {
    if(gridView1.IsGroupRow(e.RowHandle))
        e.PS.InsertPageBreak(e.Y);
}

// VB.NET
Private Sub gridView1_BeforePrintRow(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Printing.PrintRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.BeforePrintRow
    If gridView1.IsGroupRow(e.RowHandle) Then
        e.PS.InsertPageBreak(e.Y)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanaks for your reply. But I use devExpress grid control. If you can send me your email address I can send u sample project.
Thanks

Comment: Please review my answer again, because it is about the DevExpress [GridControl](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3461) and its [GridView](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3464).

Comment: Thanks friend.
I modify your code. IsGroupRow(e.RowHandle + 1)
Now its work.

Did you know table brake and 1 row space and again next group start. (Same question But without page break).
Thanks